# How to new up a service class which contains dependency of other previously registered services inside ConfigureServices() in .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to manually instantiate an object inside ConfigureServices() which comprises of the dependency of the previously registered services. For Eg:

```
ConfigureServices(){

 services.AddSingleton<IService1, Service1>();
 services.AddSingleton<IService2, Service2>();

// Now I need to use the above registered services in the following created object

 SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass(GetRequiredService(IService1), GetRequiredService(Service2))

// I am doing a new up of SomeClass since I need to use it elsewhere inside this method itself.

}
```

Please provide a solution how to manage the above code scenario.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You can simply use DI to respective class from constructor.

Comment: Agree with @KiranJoshi and here's [DI document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0).